# Regex (regular expressions), replace the second occurence in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

This is an example of the string that's being worked with:

```
xxxxxx[xxxxxx][7][xxxxxx][9][xxxxxx]
```

I'm having a little trouble matching the second occurrence of a match, I want to return the 2nd square brackets with a number inside. I have some regex finding the first square backets with numbers in a string:

```
\[+[0-9]+\]
```

This returns [7], however I want to return [9].

I'm using Javascript's replace function, the following regex matches the second occurrence (the [9]) in regex testeing apps, however it isn't replaced correctly in the Javascript replace function:

```
(?:.*?(\[+[0-9]+\])){2}
```

My question is how do I use the above regex to replace the [9] in Javasctipt or is there another regex that matches the second occurrence of a number in square brackets.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `xxx` is just any string, and not necessarily a number, then this might be what you want:

```
(\[[0-9]+\]\[.*?\])\[([0-9]+)\]
```

This looks for the second number in `[]`. Replace it with `$1[<replacement>]`. [Play with it on rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/0TP2Dcx71H).

Your regular expression fails to work as intended because groups followed by `+` only end up holding the *last* `[xxx]`.

Comment: Why are you using `{3}` as a quantifier? This doesn't appear to be a "there will always be three tags before the one we want, and one after" situation, shouldn't you base the regex on the actual requirements stated by the asker? Personally, I would use `/(\[\d+\](?:\[.*?\D.*?\])*)(\[\d+\])/\1[replacement]/`

Comment: @Anon We don't know that `xxx` isn't a number. I assumed it was, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I've added another regex which will replace the second `[<number>]`.

Comment: @marcog: The asker mentioned he wanted "the second match", so I think we can presume that `[xxx]` doesn't match the same thing as `[9]`. Though it is unclear whether `[xxx]` can be things like `[123]`, or whether it must have something that isn't a digit in it.

Comment: @Anon Do you agree with my new regex?

Comment: @marcog: You're missing a backslash near the end of the first group, but other than that it looks good.

Comment: @Anon Technically it's not required, but I'll add it in.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
result = subject.replace(/(\[\d\]\[[^\]]+\])\[\d\]/, "$1[replace]");
```

As a commented regex:

```
(       # capture the following in backref 1:
\[\d\]  # first occurrence of [digit]
\[      # [
 [^\]]+ # any sequence of characters except ]
\]      # ]
)       # end of capturing group
\[\d\]  # match the second occurence of [digit]
```

If the number of `[xxx]` groups between the first and second `[digit]` group is variable, then use

```
result = subject.replace(/(\[\d\](?:\[[^\]]+\])*?)\[\d\]/, "$1[replace]");
```

By surrounding the part that matches the `[xxx]` groups with (non-capturing) parentheses and the lazy quantifier `*?` I'm asking the regex engine to match as few of those groups as possible, but as many as necessary so the next group is a `[digit]` group.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log( "xxxxxx[xxxxxx][7][xxxxxx][9][xxxxxx]".replace(
/^(.*\[[0-9]+\].*)(\[[0-9]+\])(.*)$/, 
'$1[15]$3')); // replace with matches before ($1) and after ($3) your match ($2)
```

returns:

```
// xxxxxx[xxxxxx][7][xxxxxx][15][xxxxxx]
```

It will match where [n] is preceeded by 1 set of brackets with numbers inside.

Comment: Not sure if this is important, but this fails on [1][2][3] - replaces the last [3]. Maybe the OP should provide some tests...